# Safari - Iframes causing flicker on page change

Tags: html, css, safari

I am moving a navigable site into an iframe that now has other frames surrounding it.

Everything works normally however now in Safari when a link is clicked in the main iframe the iframe goes blank momentarily then the pages loads. Usually the user would only notice changes in elements that have changed. So the main site template would appear to have not been reloaded.

This is how the site used to behave outside the iframe and in Firefox it behaves that way despite now being in an iframe.

Is there any way to stop Safari re-loading the entire page from scratch each time a link is clicked in the iframe?

Answer (score 0):

The answer has been tested and is completely serious, be warned!

So the Safari white flicker only occurs when a Javascript file is called in the head or the body, and from the same domain.

So you can include Javascript files in the head as normal from an external domain and no flicker, change it to your own domain and it flickers.

To get even more weird if you include the local javascript files in the body there is a lesser flicker, after the body it completely goes away.

This must be a bug!

Below is a basic example, clicking the link causes the flicker.

Test page HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="inzu.ico" >

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

</head>
<body>
<iframe id="iframe" src="testframe.html" style="height:600px"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Frame with flicker:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="/something.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style>
body{
    background:red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<a href="testframe.html">TEST</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Frame with no flicker:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
body{
    background:red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<a href="testframe.html">TEST</a>
</body>
<script src="/something.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: By the way the JS file can be empty or not even exists and the same error occurs.